Problem from the 2023 ICTM State Division AA contest.
Let $S$ be the sum of all values of $x$, for which $\frac{6x^{-2}+11x^{-1}+4}{2+3x^{-1}-2x^{-2}}=3$ for $x \neq 0$, $x \neq a$, $x \neq b$, $a > b$, $a \neq 0$, and $b \neq 0$. Determine the value of $(2S + 4a + 6b).$
This is a problem that came up during my math group as we were preparing for a competition. Now my idea to solve this was to first get a quadratic by multiplying the fraction by $\frac{x^2}{x^2}$ and then multiplying the equation by the denominator to get a quadratic on both sides. Then I subtracted over and found a quadratic which satisfied the conditions and got $4$. However, the correct answer was $-4$ and I am not sure how to get that. Could someone explain? Also could someone make a tag for this?

Where does $a$ and $b$ come from? There is no information about $a$ and $b$ other than that they are not equal to $x$ or $0$ and $a > b$, so this is not enough information to determine $2S+4a+6b$

Welcome to MSE. Your question mentions S, a, b but I can only see S in the original question. Also, it helps a lot if you show the work you have already done when asking questions such as "where did I go wrong?"

So I believe the $a$ and $b$ represent like $ax^2+bx+c$ standard form.

Here’s what I did to get $-4$:
Follow the $\frac{x^2}{x^2}$ step
Subtract $3$ from both sides, and multiply by the denominator to sum the top to a quadratic, totaling:
$\frac{-2x^2+2x+12}{2x^2+3x-2}=0$
Now, the equation will be invalid for $a$ and $b$ when the denominator $2x^2+3x-2$ equals $0$.
Those values are $-2$ and $0.5$ (factor, quadratic formula, graph, whatever). Since $a>b,$ $a=0.5$ and $b=-2.$
Now, for the solution $S$, the numerator needs to be $0$ when $x$ doesn’t equal $a$ or $b$ (as then the denominator doesn’t matter). Solving the numerator $-2x^2+2x+12=0,$ we get $x=3$ and $-2,$ but $-2=b$ so we have to use $3.$
Therefore we get $S$ to be $3$, and $2(3)+4(0.5)+6(-2)=6+2-12= -4.$

Did you pull out an "$a$" out of thin air? Anyways jokes aside, what's $a$ in your answer?

@Gwen The answer says $a=0.5$ and $b=-2$. Based on reading this answer, I understand the question now: When it says $x\neq 0, x\neq a, x\neq b$, the question is expressing the domain of the function $(6x^{-2}+11x^{-1}+4)/(2+3x^{-1}-2x^{-2})$, so we need to figure out the domain of this function and then find $a$ and $b$ accordingly. As this answer shows, this function is undefined whenever $x=0$ and whenever $2x^2+3x-2=0$, so the $x\neq a, x\neq b$ part of the domain must come from the roots of $2x^2+3x-2$ being excluded from the domain, i.e. $a$ and $b$ are the roots of $2x^2+3x-2$

ohh, that makes much more sense now, thank you.
